# JQuery - Hide element after Classes have been removed

Tags: jquery

A little new to development so bear with me.

I have a button that removes the class '.hidden' when clicked. Once all '.hidden' classes are removed, I want to hide the '.load-more' element.

```js
var $grid_item_div = $('.grid-item');
grid_item_show = 20;

if ($grid_item_div.length > 5) {
  $grid_item_div.slice(-10).addClass("hidden");
}

$('body').on('click', '.show-content', function() {
  $('.hidden:lt(' + grid_item_show + ')').removeClass('hidden');
});

$grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true
});

$('body').on('click', '.show-content', function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
  <div class="grid-item hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="load-more"><button class="show-content">Load More</button</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ddavis82/pen/eYmzOYd

What would be the best method to accomplish this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please attach the code for the load-more click handler and have a good read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid down votes in the future

Comment: Does Sean's answer not work for you?

Comment: No sorry. It doesn't Here's it is with his answer https://codepen.io/ddavis82/pen/eYmzOYd

Comment: He does mention in comments "put it in the code that fires in your button click to remove hidden" in your pen, you have not done that and if you do, it works fine

Comment: I totally missed that! Thank you for pointing that out. It works now :)

Comment: You can mark his solution as correct if everything is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this validation in te action of removing the .hidden after you remove the hidden class:

```
if (!$(".hidden")[0]){
   $(".load-more").hide();
}
```

Comment: .load-more still showing after reaching the end. I updated the original question with more details

Comment: I couldnt get your masonry grid working, but for reply your question I just put my code below this line: 
`$('.hidden:lt(' + grid_item_show + ')').removeClass('hidden');`
And it works as I understand you want, take a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/zu0qgtav/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `hidden` hides an element...

```
 $('.grid-item').removeClass('hidden');
 $('.load-more').addClass('hidden');
```

EDIT after thinking about it you're removing hidden class one at a time so you would probably want to check if any more exist instead...

```
if (!$('.grid-item.hidden').length)//checks if there's any left
{
    $('.load-more').addClass('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that hide .load-more from the beginning? I'm needing to hide .load-more once all instances of .hidden are removed.

Comment: put it in the code that fires in your button click to remove hidden

Comment: One thing I left out, In the situation Load More only removes one .hidden at a time.   Once all instances of .hidden are removed, how would you then hide Load More

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me: https://codepen.io/ddavis82/pen/eYmzOYd

Comment: @Dustin put his code in your click handler as mentioned in comment above